Can ideal gas equation $PV = nRT$ be used in the intermediate stages of a irreversible and reversible process?
Suppose we have two processes, one is reversible and the other is irreversible. The ideal gas undergoes from state A to state B in both processes.
I want to know that can I apply the formula $PV = nRT$ during all the intermediate stages or points between the states A and B in the case of a reversible and irreversible process?

Don't think so (at least for the irreversible case). The ideal gas equation applies to systems in equilibrium.

Do you assume that the process is "infinitely slow" or "quasi static" in each case?

@Miyase The reversible process happens via infinte number of steps and the irreversible process occurs in finite number of steps.


Can ideal gas equation (PV = nRT) be used in the intermediate stages
of a irreversible and reversible process?

The ideal gas equation applies to the equilibrium states. Since an ideal gas is not in equilibrium all during an irreversible process the equation does not apply to the intermediate stages. It only applies to the initial and final equilibrium states.
Since an ideal gas is in equilibrium throughout a reversible process the equation applies during the intermediate stages, as well as the initial and final equilibrium states.
Hope this helps.

For intermediate states of an irreversible process, the ideal gas law can be applied locally, as Pv=RT, where v is the local molar volume (inverse of local molar density).

@ChetMiller As a practical matter, in order to apply the ideal gas law how does one determine the local molecular volume?

Also, how would one apply the gas law result based on the local molecular volume?

You need to solve the PDEs:  continuity eqn, Navier Stokes, thermal energy balance.

@ChetMiller Assuming i did (and I have no idea how to do so), what about my second question.

If one of your spatially local dependent variables is p and another is T, then you would calculate v locally from RT/p or local density from pM/RT.

@ChetMiller I understand that. My question is what do we do with it since it’s not an equilibrium state as p and T will vary in time? What’s the utility?

You assume local state (spatially) is a thermodynamic equilibrium stste

@ChetMiller but for a closed system aren’t the spacial temperature and pressure differences changing in time until the process ends and the differences disappear?

Yes, but we are also alllowing the other state functions per mole (or mass ) to have their local equilibrium values at the local T and P.

@ChetMiller I feel like I'm going in circles.  Let me put it a different way. Would you use the ideal gas equation for the intermediate stage of an irreversible process differently than using the ideal gas equation for the intermediate stage of a reversible process and, if so, how?

I don't know how to answer this.  All I can say is that I would use it locally rather than globally.

@ChetMiller But for what purpose would you use it? That's all I'm askiing.

You would use it in solving the coupled PDEs that I mentioned.
